# How can I get Windows 11 to show both headphones and headset as separate devices in playback devices for my Bluetooth headset?

Tags: audio, bluetooth, windows-11, headphones, headset

In Windows 10's "Playback" tab in the "Sound" window, I would get two devices listed for each pair of Bluetooth headphones I would have connected. For my ear buds, we first have the buds listed as headphones and then as headset. The headset device is intentionally disabled by me. We'll get to why in a moment. On a clean install of Windows 11 on the same machine with the same devices / drivers, I am only shown the headphones:
[image]

**How can I force Windows 11 to show me my buds as both headphones and headsets just like in Windows 10?**

The reason I want this is because it gives me control over what Bluetooth profile is used with my ear buds because of the oligophrenic way Windows handles this.

Say I am listening in glorious A2DP stereo to a podcast while working. After some time, I have to join a Slack call. When I enter the call, the sane thing for Windows to do would be  to switch to the headset profile but it more often then not does not do that. As a result, I could hear everyone on the call in stereo quality but they can't hear me.

On windows 10 the fix is simple: open the playback devices window (pictured above), disable the "Headphones" version of my buds and enable the "Headset" version. Lo and behold, I can now both hear and speak on my Slack call.

What happens after the call ends and I want to continue listening to the podcast? That's right, Windows refuses to switch back to stereo mode and I am stuck listening to my podcast in potato quality. Back in the playback devices window I go, disable the headset and enable the headphones.

In windows 11 I can no longer do that. Sometimes I can fix it by disabling and re-enabling Bluetooth in windows or turning the buds on or off. Other times, the only thing that works is going into services and restarting the "Windows Audio Endpoint Builder" service.

Bluetooth headphones/headsets have always been more of a handicap than a feature in Windows but with windows 11, instead of actually fixing it, they somehow made it worse. How hard can it be? Phones have been doing it for decades...

I already tried checking every combination of Bluetooth services inside the properties of my buds but doesn't seem to affect the problem:
[image]

Comment: What model are your computer, Bluetooth adapter *and" driver, headset?

Comment: Galaxy buds pro paired to either a Lenovo T480 with Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC (not sure what model since it is hidden as though it is a state secret) and the latest driver from lenovo website, or to an Asus G55VW with a broadcom bluetooth chip (again, not sure what model) and the latest drivers from Asus

Comment: Did you try the generic Windows driver? (By deleting the Lenovo driver)

Comment: No, but I'm not sure what difference it would make. The Lenovo driver is for Win 11, but I tried the Win 10 driver. Asus dropped support a long time ago so the only driver is for win 10. These same adapters / drivers worked on Win 10. I'll give it a try, though.

Comment: Wifi disconected and 3 restarts later, I finally stopped Windows from searching and reinstalling the Intel drivers each time I remove them so that I was using only the generic driver. Still, the problem remains.

Comment: If you have tried the Windows 10 driver on Windows 11 and this has changed nothing, then the problem is with Windows 11 itself. You might try to install from the Microsoft Store the [Galaxy Buds app](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/galaxy-buds/9NHTLWTKFZNB?hl=en-us&gl=US).

Comment: Have you advanced with the problem?

Comment: No, I'm afraid not. The app doesn't give me the option to switch the profile. If it does, it's buried deeper than the Mariana trench. It does have a voice detection feature but it's not used to switch profiles. Instead, it uses it to detect if other people are speaking to me and disable noise cancelling so that I can hear them or other some-such. In fact, the app doesn't seem to change anything at all inside Windows. It just seems to change the configuration on the buds themselves. Besides, I also use a pair of Sony headphones sometimes. There is no app for those headphones.

Comment: Hey, have you been able to spot the cause of the problem?
Have same issue here

Comment: Nope. Knowing Microsoft, it probably won't be solved in our lifetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have tried the Windows 10 driver on Windows 11 and this has
changed nothing, then the problem is with Windows 11 itself and not with
the driver.

The solution to the problem must come from Microsoft.
The most you can do is signal the problem in the Feedback Hub and wait
for a fix (or rollback to Windows 10 before the limit of 10 days expires).